# Android things device NOT found on Android studio 3.5

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-studio

After I upgrade **Android studio to 3.5**, I can't find the android things device to run on like before. I have already connect the device in the command line using adb and it said the device is **connected**.

My device is raspberry-pi 3.

Comment: Could you provide more details, can you describe more on what is this "thing"

Comment: you can check it out here Android things :
https://developer.android.com/things

Comment: What Android things command are you trying to use?

Comment: I actually solve it... It is because of my wire.I change the wire and it work.And that wire doesn't work on any phone. Thank you

Comment: You should post that as an answer

Comment: Yes, please always post, and accept , an answer when you find the solution yourself. That will help others in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it. It was because of my wire. I changed the wire and it works. And that wire doesn't work on any phone.